# 403 (forbidden) on end user's console

Tags: javascript, http-status-code-403

I have an application that seems to be working across the internet. But I fielded a call from an end-user who is having difficulty using the [website](http://www.gis.leg.mn/iMaps/districts/)

I asked her to send a screenshot of the console error and recieved this: 
[image]

From searching stackoverflow it looks like its a permissions issue, but the site works for everyone else. Is this on her end or mine?

**UPDATE** I should've mentioned that is user works from a school. Perhaps her IT admin has blocked some internet resources?

Comment: I can confirm your site working from Sweden.

Answer (score 1):

**Have end-user tried different browser? i would say it's some plugin stopping to load that script. If your app is working everywhere then it can't be your app. Ask end-use to try another browser and for check if end-user has any plugin witch can also cause this.**

Comment: Thanks, she did try it from IE... I suspect you are right on the plugin issue, or maybe some browser JS blocking setting?

Comment: Yes i believe so.. i would suggest you don't need to do anything just say end-user to find bug on her/his PC :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem may also come from lealfet or google map.

We can se that the page is currently loaded, css ans content seems fine, only the map part seems to be broken. So i don't think there is a problem with your server/website, I would put the fault on the others.

Note : we see that leaflet only is concerned when looking carefully at the screenshot.

Edit : in some cases, you can make a local copy of these external file, check whether the user need them or not, then load them as rescue.

Update : Either the school did block leaflet, or leaflet did automatically  block the school as their bandwich use can excess what they allows by user, or due to abuse of any kind.

Comment: Did the map load for you? She is only receiving the spinner (not loading)

Comment: Yes, from France this is fine.

Comment: Updated the reason part :)